# If I click the popup related button, Table Row Highlighted in Tailwindcss and Alpine js

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

If I click customize link/button, In that table first 2 rows are highlighted and it was hide the customize popup.

If I click the first row View log, Add Note, Edit Time means In that table second row is highlighted and it was hide the popups.

If I click the second row View log, Add Note, Edit Time means it is working perfectly.

How can I fix the code? I also need to arrange it so that adding "N" number of rows means it should not override the popup.

[image: While Customize button is clicked]

[image: While first row popup button is clicked]

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="m-16">
  <div>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between gap-8 py-6">
      <p class="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">Daily Attendance</p>
      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
        <button class="text-sm font-semibold text-blue-600" @click="showModal = true">
            Customize
        </button>
        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50"
            x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
            <!-- Modal inner -->
            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-lg"
                @click.away="showModal = false"
                x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                <!-- Title / Close-->
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                        Customize fields
                    </p>
                    <span @click="showModal = false">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- content -->
                <div class="w-full mt-4 space-y-4">
                    <ul class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2">
                        <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                            <input class="w-4 h-4" checked disabled type="checkbox">
                            <p>Not Punched</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                            <input class="w-4 h-4" checked disabled type="checkbox">
                            <p>Present</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button
                        class="px-3 py-2 font-semibold text-center text-white bg-blue-600 rounded w-36">Save
                        Fields</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="relative">
      <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll ">
        <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
          <thead class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
              <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">
                Name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="p-4">
                In Time</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
            <tr>
              <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                  <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="">
                  <div>
                    <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John
                                                Doe</a>
                    <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs
                                            </button>

                      <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- Modal inner -->
                        <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                          <!-- Title / Close-->
                          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                              Attendance Log
                            </p>
                            <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                          </div>
                          <!-- content -->
                          <div>
                            <p><span>Elavarasan</span> |
                              <span>25-04-2022</span>
                            </p>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">
                                                Add Note</button>
                      <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- Modal inner -->
                        <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                          <!-- Title / Close-->
                          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <div>
                              <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                Add Note
                              </p>
                              <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">
                                Elavarasan | 27-11-2023
                              </p>
                            </div>

                            <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                            <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                </path>
                                                            </svg>
                                                        </span>
                          </div>
                          <!-- content -->
                          <div class="w-full mt-4">
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                              <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                              <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                              <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="p-4">
                <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <span class="text-sm text-gray-900">
                                        10:00 AM
                                    </span>
                  <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                    <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600"><span>
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z">
                                                    </path>
                                                </svg></span></button>
                    <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                      <!-- Modal inner -->
                      <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                        <!-- Title / Close-->
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                          <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                            Edit Time
                          </p>
                          <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- content -->
                        <div class="w-full mt-4">
                          <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                              <div>
                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                  <option value="">AM</option>
                                  <option value="">PM</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                              <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                              <div class="w-1/2">
                                <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                    <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="">
                    <div>
                      <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John
                                                  Doe</a>
                      <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                    </div>
  
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs
                                              </button>
  
                        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                          <!-- Modal inner -->
                          <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                            <!-- Title / Close-->
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                              <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                Attendance Log
                              </p>
                              <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                              <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                  </path>
                                                              </svg>
                                                          </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- content -->
                            <div>
                              <p><span>Elavarasan</span> |
                                <span>25-04-2022</span>
                              </p>
                            </div>
  
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">
                                                  Add Note</button>
                        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                          <!-- Modal inner -->
                          <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                            <!-- Title / Close-->
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                              <div>
                                <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                                  Add Note
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">
                                  Elavarasan | 27-11-2023
                                </p>
                              </div>
  
                              <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                              <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12">
                                                                  </path>
                                                              </svg>
                                                          </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- content -->
                            <div class="w-full mt-4">
                              <div>
                                <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                                <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                                <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                                <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
  
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="p-4">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-900">
                                          10:00 AM
                                      </span>
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600"><span>
                                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                                                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z">
                                                      </path>
                                                  </svg></span></button>
                      <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- Modal inner -->
                        <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                          <!-- Title / Close-->
                          <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                            <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">
                              Edit Time
                            </p>
                            <span @click="showModal = false">
                                                          <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                                              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                                          </svg>
                                                      </span>
                          </div>
                          <!-- content -->
                          <div class="w-full mt-4">
                            <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                              <div>
                                <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                                <div>
                                  <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                  <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                  <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number">
                                  <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                  <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                    <option value="">AM</option>
                                    <option value="">PM</option>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                                <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                                <div class="w-1/2">
                                  <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
  
              </tr>
            <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
        <select id="jobtype" name="jobtype" autocomplete="jobtype" class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base">
          <option>10</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>100</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm" aria-label="Pagination">
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        1
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        2
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100">
                        3
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        4
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100">
                        5
                    </a>
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
            <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We don't review or fix code. And definitely don't ask us to do anything ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

For the customize modal, consider increasing the `z-index` to be greater than the elements that get "highlighted". When two elements have the same `z-index` in the same stacking context, the element declared later in the DOM is drawn above elements before, so we can increase the `z-index` to ensure it is drawn over other elements.

You issue comes from the fact that the *View log* and *Add note* modals are inside this element:

```html
<td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
```

This element would be the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) for the modals. This means that relative to subsequent similar `<td>` elements in the document, the subsequent elements would be layered above. This is because again, when two elements have the same `z-index` in the same stacking context, the element declared later in the DOM is drawn above elements before.

You could consider upgrading to a more recent version of Alpine.js to use the [`x-teleport` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/teleport), so that the modals are outside of these stacking contexts.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/3.13.5/cdn.js" integrity="sha512-8IPRU0MPrge2KfSxkAtO8pIkaMzThW/MBSvPqcyVisSymLWC986buo27pKAt5mWXmt58dT6jIsw7h8NNugtRwg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="m-16">
    <div>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between gap-8 py-6">
        <p class="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">Daily Attendance</p>
        <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
          <button class="text-sm font-semibold text-blue-600" @click="showModal = true">Customize</button>
          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
            <!-- Modal inner -->
            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-lg" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
              <!-- Title / Close-->
              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Customize fields</p>
                <span @click="showModal = false">
                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </div>
              <!-- content -->
              <div class="w-full mt-4 space-y-4">
                <ul class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2">
                  <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <input class="w-4 h-4" checked disabled type="checkbox" />
                    <p>Not Punched</p>
                  </li>
                  <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <input class="w-4 h-4" checked disabled type="checkbox" />
                    <p>Present</p>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <button class="px-3 py-2 font-semibold text-center text-white bg-blue-600 rounded w-36">Save Fields</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="relative">
        <div class="w-full overflow-x-scroll">
          <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 table-auto">
            <thead class="text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-white uppercase bg-blue-600 whitespace-nowrap">
              <tr class="py-4 divide-x">
                <th scope="col" class="sticky left-0 z-10 p-4 bg-blue-600">Name</th>
                <th scope="col" class="p-4">In Time</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-sm bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200 whitespace-nowrap">
              <tr>
                <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                    <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div>
                      <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                      <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs</button>
                        <template x-teleport="body">
                          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                            <!-- Modal inner -->
                            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                              <!-- Title / Close-->
                              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Attendance Log</p>
                                <span @click="showModal = false">
                                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <!-- content -->
                              <div>
                                <p>
                                  <span>Elavarasan</span> |
                                  <span>25-04-2022</span>
                                </p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">Add Note</button>
                        <template x-teleport="body">
                          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                            <!-- Modal inner -->
                            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                              <!-- Title / Close-->
                              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <div>
                                  <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Add Note</p>
                                  <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">Elavarasan | 27-11-2023</p>
                                </div>

                                <span @click="showModal = false">
                                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <!-- content -->
                              <div class="w-full mt-4">
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                                  <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                                  <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                                  <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="p-4">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 10:00 AM </span>
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600">
                        <span>
                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z"></path></svg
                        ></span>
                      </button>
                      <template x-teleport="body">
                        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                          <!-- Modal inner -->
                          <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                            <!-- Title / Close-->
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                              <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Edit Time</p>
                              <span @click="showModal = false">
                                <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                </svg>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- content -->
                            <div class="w-full mt-4">
                              <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                                  <div>
                                    <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number" />
                                    <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                    <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number" />
                                    <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                    <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                      <option value="">AM</option>
                                      <option value="">PM</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                                  <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                                  <div class="w-1/2">
                                    <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </template>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="sticky left-0 z-30 w-full p-4 bg-white whitespace-nowrap">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2 w-max">
                    <img class="w-8 h-8 rounded-full" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div>
                      <a href="" class="font-medium text-blue-600">John Doe</a>
                      <p class="text-xs text-gray-600">NA_1110</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }" @keydown.escape="showModal = false">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">View Logs</button>

                        <template x-teleport="body">
                          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                            <!-- Modal inner -->
                            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                              <!-- Title / Close-->
                              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Attendance Log</p>
                                <span @click="showModal = false">
                                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <!-- content -->
                              <div>
                                <p>
                                  <span>Elavarasan</span> |
                                  <span>25-04-2022</span>
                                </p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                      <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                        <button @click="showModal = true" class="text-sm text-blue-600">Add Note</button>
                        <template x-teleport="body">
                          <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                            <!-- Modal inner -->
                            <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                              <!-- Title / Close-->
                              <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                                <div>
                                  <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Add Note</p>
                                  <p class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-600">Elavarasan | 27-11-2023</p>
                                </div>

                                <span @click="showModal = false">
                                  <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <!-- content -->
                              <div class="w-full mt-4">
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Add Notes</label>
                                  <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center gap-4 pt-6">
                                  <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded">Cancel</button>
                                  <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded">Save</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td class="p-4">
                  <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-900"> 10:00 AM </span>
                    <div x-data="{ 'showModal': false }">
                      <button @click="showModal = true" class="flex items-center text-blue-600">
                        <span>
                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 mr-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z"></path></svg
                        ></span>
                      </button>
                      <template x-teleport="body">
                        <div class="fixed inset-0 z-30 flex items-center justify-center overflow-auto bg-black bg-opacity-50" x-show="showModal" style="display: none">
                          <!-- Modal inner -->
                          <div class="w-11/12 px-6 py-4 mx-auto text-left bg-white rounded shadow-lg md:max-w-md" @click.away="showModal = false" x-transition:enter="motion-safe:ease-out duration-300" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100">
                            <!-- Title / Close-->
                            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                              <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Edit Time</p>
                              <span @click="showModal = false">
                                <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
                                </svg>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- content -->
                            <div class="w-full mt-4">
                              <div class="space-y-2 divide-y">
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Time</label>
                                  <div>
                                    <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number" />
                                    <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                    <input class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md" type="number" />
                                    <span class="font-bold">:</span>
                                    <select class="w-16 p-2 border border-gray-400 rounded-md">
                                      <option value="">AM</option>
                                      <option value="">PM</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="">Reason</label>
                                  <textarea rows="3" class="relative block w-full p-2 px-3 py-3 mt-1 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 focus:z-10" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full gap-4 pt-4">
                                  <div class="w-1/2">
                                    <button class="w-full p-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-md">Update</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </template>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 pt-6 lg:flex-row lg:justify-between">
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <p class="pr-2 text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
          <select id="jobtype" name="jobtype" autocomplete="jobtype" class="block w-16 p-1 mt-1 text-sm bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded shadow-sm disabled:cursor-not-allowed focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-600 focus:border-blue-600 sm:text-base">
            <option>10</option>
            <option>25</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <nav class="relative z-0 inline-flex -space-x-px shadow-sm" aria-label="Pagination">
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md hover:bg-blue-100">
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-left -->
              <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
              </svg>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"> 1 </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"> 2 </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative items-center hidden px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 md:inline-flex hover:bg-blue-100"> 3 </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"> 4 </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-100"> 5 </a>
            <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md hover:bg-blue-100">
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-right -->
              <svg class="w-5 h-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```